# Insert function name with php

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a simple task, insert a second function name under "onmouseover" but probably something is wrong with the syntax.

```
echo '<div onmouseover="changeText(); <?php if($title==""){echo changeViz();}; ?> ">';
```

I probably need to escape some quotes and add some, but i can't figure out the correct solution.
Thanks

Nothing it's working. Let me give you the complete code...:

```
echo '<div class="frame" onmouseover="changeText(\''.$text[$i].'\'); <?php if($title[$i]==""){echo changeViz();}; ?>">';
```

Answer (score 4):

You are nesting `<?php ?>` inside existing php code, which is a syntax error. Instead, concatenate in the javascript function `changeViz()` as a quoted string.

This version uses a [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to duplicate the `if()` statement you had originally.

```
echo '<div onmouseover="changeText(); ' . ($title == '' ? 'changeViz();' : '') .  '">';
```

The ternary operation here will concatenate `changeViz();` onto the `echo` string if `$title == ""`, or otherwise just concatenate on an empty string.

#### Update after seeing full code:

You have the quote escaping correct in the first part.

```
echo '<div class="frame" onmouseover="changeText(\'' . $text[$i] . '\'); ' . ($title == '' ? 'changeViz();' : '') .  '">';
```

Comment: @RyanB I think the quotes are all correct, since the final `"` closes the onmouseover. In any case, I changed them to single quotes on the PHP side to be clear.

Comment: wouldn't the first " after `title ==` end the pair for the mouseover?

Comment: @RyanB It's a different string, in a different context. Inside the single quotes, the opening `"` doesnt need escaping and isn't parsed as an open string as far as PHP is concerned.  The pair of double quotes after `$title` (which I thought I changed to single) are a separate string as far as PHP is concerned as well, and won't close any opened in the previous string.

Comment: It might have been while you were updating

Comment: @chitoiudaniel Sorry, looks like the ternary statement needs to be enclosed in `()`. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your code much more readable if you do not try to do everything in one line:

```
$onmouseover_action = "changeText(); ";
if($title==""){
    $onmouseover_action .= "changeViz(); ";
}
echo '<div onmouseover="'.$onmouseover_action.'">';
```

It makes your code easier to maintain, and you have less need to comment it, because it describes itself quite much better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo '<div class="frame" onmouseover="changeText(\''.$text[$i].'\'); '. ($title[$i]=="")?'changeViz();':'').'">';
```